# Magento2 how to show header and footer in Luma basic checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, theme-fallback

I'm using Magento2, Hyva-Themes, and I've enabled the checkout from admin with this path `frontend/Magento/luma`.
Now here, I can show header and footer from admin, but they are the default header and footer and not the ones I've got in all the other pages.

In `checkout_index_index.xml` I've tried to set

```
   <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
```

but still they remain the same default header and footer. There's a way that allows me to add MY header and MY footer in the chekout page?

I was reading these docs, https://docs.hyva.io/hyva-themes/luma-theme-fallback/index.html
but I can't find a way to easily set my header and footer.

If you can help guys it would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't give whole code. but just a general hint, overwrite checkout_index_index.xml file into child and by calling the reference container you can just set an template with your theme i.e hvya-theme:footer.html.
please check.
Thank you

Comment: Yes but since the checkout is handled by less and knockout.js and header and footer are handled by tailwind it doesn't take the styles. But I will try thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way you just need to change the layout in the file checkout_index_index.xml from 'checkout' to '1column'

from

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

to

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Comment: Hi! I think I've tried this before but didn't work, however I will try again thanks!